# Getting values from webpage using Simple HTML Dom library

Tags: php, php-5.3, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get values from a table in a webpage and for that I'm using Simple HTML Dom library. This is how my code looks like:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.lvbp.com/posicion.html');

$arr = array();
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    array_push($arr, $e->innertext);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';

for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    str_replace("", "-", $arr[$i]);
    print_r($arr[$i]);
}
```

And I get this as output when `print_r($arr)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>       EQUIPOS      J      G      P      Vent    
    [1] => 
    [2] =>       Navegantes      11      8      3      0    
    [3] =>       Tigres      11      8      3      0    
    [4] =>       Caribes      11      6      5      2    
    [5] =>       Leones      11      6      5      2    
    [6] =>       Aguilas      11      5      6      3    
    [7] =>       Tiburones      10      4      6      3.5    
    [8] =>       Cardenales      10      3      7      4.5    
    [9] =>       Bravos      11      3      8      5    
)
```

But from here I need to get separately meaning "Navegantes", "11", "8" and so on ... for each array position. For that my last code:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    str_replace("", "-", $arr[$i]);
    print_r($arr[$i]);
}
```

But it's not working since I get this as result:

```
Navegantes 11 8 3 0 Tigres 11 8 3 0 Caribes 11 6 5 2 Leones 11 6 5 2 Aguilas 11 5 6 3 Tiburones 10 4 6 3.5 Cardenales 10 3 7 4.5 Bravos 11 3 8 5
```

What I'm missing? Any help?

**UPDATE**

This is how my code looks like based on suggestions:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lvbp.com/posicion.html');

$arr = array();
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    $narr = array();
    foreach ($e->find('td') as $vp) {
        array_push($narr, $vp->plaintext);
    }
    $arr[] = array($narr);
}
```

Comment: Use $arr[$i]=str_replace("", "-", $arr[$i]); instead of str_replace("", "-", $arr[$i]);

Comment: @Subin changed but get the same result, no dashes (-) between words

Comment: Are you trying to get each values of **td** in a **tr** as an array ?

Comment: @Subin, yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $e) {
 $narr=array();
 foreach($e->find('td') as $vp){
  array_push($narr,$vp->plaintext);
 }
 $arr[]=array($narr);
}
```

instead of :

```
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    array_push($arr, $e->innertext);
}
```

And drop the code :

```
for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    str_replace("", "-", $arr[$i]);
    print_r($arr[$i]);
}
```

You will get an array with keys as **tr** tags and their values as each **td** of **tr**.

Comment: No, you're wrong I get this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/reader/parser/posicion.php on line 29, referer: http://devserver/reader/parser/` where line 29 is `foreach($code->find('td') as $vp){ ...`

Comment: Are you sure you replaced correctly ? Because on my side it's working.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of simple_html_dom ? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes I'm downloaded few seconds ago

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39843/discussion-between-subin-and-reynier)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an aproach:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.lvbp.com/posicion.html";

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($url);

// parse rows
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $i => $row) {

    // Skip the second empty row
    if ($i == 1)
        continue;

    // parse and print cells
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $j => $col) {
        echo $col->plaintext;
        echo "|";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}


// Clear DOM object (needed essentially when using many)
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

[Live DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z2c-9sd)